# How do I run an inference on a TensorFlow 2.x model in AWS Sagemaker?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, amazon-sagemaker

I have created a MobileNetV2 model that can classify fruits in 5 categories (apples, carrots, cucumbers, pears, and zucchini). I have uploaded the .h5 model to an AWS Sagemaker Notebook Instance and created the folder hierarchy with a protobuff file. I also successfully created a Sagemaker endpoint. However, when trying to run inference on this endpoint with an image, I receive an error claiming that the input tensor name is not found in the model Graph.

I used the protobuff file to find the input tensor name, and it appears to be input_1:0. I am not sure where the error is coming from.

A link to the notebook (if you want to see the full thing) is here: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KqflVvWbZbXNzMQsnuqyCcV6ewJmMovC?usp=sharing

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np
import json
endpoint_name = 'tensorflow-inference-2023-06-15-03-24-26-323'
label_names = ['apple', 'carrot', 'cucumber', 'pear', 'zucchini']

runtime = boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')

#photo = 'image-removebg-preview (4).png'
#img = Image.open(photo)
img = image.load_img("image-removebg-preview (4).png", target_size = (200,200))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis = 0)
x=x/255.0

payload = {"instances": x.tolist()}

# Invoke the endpoint
response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name, ContentType='application/json', Body=json.dumps(payload))

# Parse the response
result = json.loads(response['Body'].read().decode())
predictions = result['predictions'][0]

# Print the predicted label
predicted_label_index = np.argmax(predictions)
predicted_label = label_names[predicted_label_index]
print(predicted_label)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModelError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 19
     16 payload = {"instances": x.tolist()}
     18 # Invoke the endpoint
---> 19 response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name, ContentType='application/json', Body=json.dumps(payload))
     21 # Parse the response
     22 result = json.loads(response['Body'].read().decode())

File ~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py:530, in ClientCreator._create_api_method.<locals>._api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
    526     raise TypeError(
    527         f"{py_operation_name}() only accepts keyword arguments."
    528     )
    529 # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
--> 530 return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py:964, in BaseClient._make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
    962     error_code = parsed_response.get("Error", {}).get("Code")
    963     error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
--> 964     raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
    965 else:
    966     return parsed_response

ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (400) from primary with message "{
    "error": "Tensor input_1:0, specified in either feed_devices or fetch_devices was not found in the Graph"
}". See https://us-east-2.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-east-2#logEventViewer:group=/aws/sagemaker/Endpoints/tensorflow-inference-2023-06-15-03-24-26-323 in account 415514861026 for more information.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please test whether the output given by your function `convert_model_to_aws` in your [Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KqflVvWbZbXNzMQsnuqyCcV6ewJmMovC?usp=sharing) is correct. Follow tensorflow best practices for saving and loading the model. Sample of them are given at [Tensorflow Save and Load](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load).

Once you have verified the model, please write the handler functions in the `train.py` that you were providing to `TensorflowModel Class`. The documentation that you can follow is

1. [Deploying from Artifacts](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/tensorflow/deploying_tensorflow_serving.html#deploying-directly-from-model-artifacts)
2. [Handler functions](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/tensorflow/deploying_tensorflow_serving.html#providing-python-scripts-for-pre-post-processing)

Also please make sure the model.tar.gz is created with correctly. It should tentatively look like,

```
export
  └── Servo
        └── 0
            ├── saved_model.pb
            └── variables
                     └── ...
```